# VPN Profile installation failed

Tags: macos, vpn, apple-configurator

I have created the VPN profile below with **Apple Configuration 2**, however when I try to install it from the **System Settings**, I'm getting the error message below:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DNS</key>
            <dict>
                <key>SupplementalMatchDomainsNoSearch</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>IKEv2</key>
            <dict>
                <key>AuthName</key>
                <string>john</string>
                <key>AuthenticationMethod</key>
                <string>None</string>
                <key>ChildSecurityAssociationParameters</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>DiffieHellmanGroup</key>
                    <integer>14</integer>
                    <key>EncryptionAlgorithm</key>
                    <string>AES-256</string>
                    <key>IntegrityAlgorithm</key>
                    <string>SHA2-256</string>
                    <key>LifeTimeInMinutes</key>
                    <integer>1440</integer>
                </dict>
                <key>DeadPeerDetectionRate</key>
                <string>Medium</string>
                <key>DisableMOBIKE</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>DisableRedirect</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>EnableCertificateRevocationCheck</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>EnableFallback</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>EnablePFS</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>ExtendedAuthEnabled</key>
                <true/>
                <key>IKESecurityAssociationParameters</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>DiffieHellmanGroup</key>
                    <integer>14</integer>
                    <key>EncryptionAlgorithm</key>
                    <string>AES-256</string>
                    <key>IntegrityAlgorithm</key>
                    <string>SHA2-256</string>
                    <key>LifeTimeInMinutes</key>
                    <integer>1440</integer>
                </dict>
                <key>LocalIdentifier</key>
                <string>1.2.3.4</string>
                <key>RemoteAddress</key>
                <string>1.2.3.4</string>
                <key>RemoteIdentifier</key>
                <string>1.2.3.4</string>
                <key>UseConfigurationAttributeInternalIPSubnet</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configure les réglages VPN</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>VPN</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.vpn.managed.E00C3366-E6B6-432F-BBC3-53F7E596F5EE</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.vpn.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>E00C3366-E6B6-432F-BBC3-53F7E596F5EE</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>Proxies</key>
            <dict>
                <key>HTTPEnable</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>HTTPSEnable</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>UserDefinedName</key>
            <string>FOO</string>
            <key>VPNType</key>
            <string>IKEv2</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>vpnB3</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>MacBook-Pro.4E18BF67-71DA-4BD4-953F-412A575352EE</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>38B9A4E4-325A-4CF7-A8BC-40D186DDDD2F</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What's wrong with my profile ?

Answer (score 3):

Removing the DNS entry made it work in my case:

```
<key>DNS</key>
<dict>
    <key>SupplementalMatchDomainsNoSearch</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
```

I have used Apple Configurator 2 v2.11.1 back [in January 2020](https://www.lancom-forum.de/fragen-zum-thema-vpn-f14/ike2-mit-macos-client-bricht-nach-8min-ab-t17430.html?sid=8b77c19bd7a741fd2fd8ef9f0ff7ba90#p101864):
It **did not** add this to the profile and the import worked with 
- macOS Catalina 10.15.2 and 
- macOS Monterey 12.1.

I now use Apple Configurator 2 v2.15 (7A23):
The key **is added** automatically which makes the import fail on 
- macOS Monterey 12.1 (21C52).

There is also a little special thing: If you delete it once, it doesn't come back if you save it again via the Apple Configurator 2. It only shows up in new connections.